# memoir: custom headerstyle

Tags: memoir, fancyhdr

I have the following MWE using the `memoir`-style, where the page style places the section-title to the left side and the pagenumber to the right on **even** pages. On **odd** pages it seems that only the pagenumber appears to the left side. there is no section-title.

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\section{This is a test1}
\blindtext[10] 

\clearpage

\pagestyle{headings}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\section{This is a test2}
\blindtext[10] 

\clearpage

\section{This is a test3}
\blindtext[10] 


\end{document}
```

Does `memoir` have a default pagestyle where

- the section-title appears on the (top) RHS and pagenumber on (top) LHS on even pages
- the section-title appears on the (top) LHS and pagenumber on (top) RHS on odd pages

If not, how can this be done manually?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Does this produce the desired result?

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\pagestyle{empty}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{empty}

\section{This is a test1}
\blindtext[10] 

\clearpage

\copypagestyle{foo}{headings}
\makeevenhead{foo}{\thepage}{}{\rightmark}
\makeoddhead{foo}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{foo}

\section{This is a test2}
\blindtext[10] 

\clearpage

\section{This is a test3}
\blindtext[10] 


\end{document}
```

The relevant part of [memman is Chapter 7, *Pagination and headers*](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf), in case you want to tinker with it yourself.

---

**EDIT**: A few remarks on the `mark` commands can be found in [the documentation for the fancyhrd package](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) and in *The LaTeX Companion* book (sec. 4.3.4 in the 2nd edition).

---

**EDIT 2:**

Chapters on odd pages, sections on even ones, and moving the pagestyle definition into the preamble:

```
\documentclass[14pt, extrafontsizes]{memoir}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\copypagestyle{foo}{headings}
\makeoddhead{foo}{\rightmark}{}{\thepage}
\makeevenhead{foo}{\thepage}{}{\leftmark}
\pagestyle{foo}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Grandiose Chapter}

Extravagant chapter introductory text.

\section{Phenomenal Section}
\blindtext[10] 

\chapter{Superlative Chapter}

Extravagant chapter introductory text.

\section{Decadent Section}
\blindtext[10] 

\section{Boring Section}
\blindtext[10] 

\section{Magnificent Section}
\blindtext[10] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! Is it possible to get the chapter-title on even pages and the section title on odd pages?

Comment: As in "Chapter 1 . The Chapter Title"

Comment: @N08 The chapter title can be accessed as `\leftmark`

Comment: @N08 As @egred mentioned, the chapter is accessible via `\leftmark`; I've added a second edit, see if that does what you need. I also removed the `\aliaspagestyle` command. Must've been a typo from when I was fiddling around with the code; it doesn't really serve any purpose here. Sorry about that.

Comment: @N08 Something I just noticed: Simply compiling the document with `memoir`'s defaults actually does precisely that on my machine. Chapters on even pages; sections on odd pages. No editing to any pagestyles required here. Unless I am misunderstanding your requirements.